# What are flags in the setIO service of the UR messages

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this was a general question form me because i have been working with a UR10 and i can set the IO's to a value. I cannot set the mode however (current or voltage controlled).
i was just wondering what the flags on a pin do. The [ur_msgs/SetIO documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/ur_msgs/html/srv/SetIO.html) shows that there is a function that sets these flags.
Are flags the parameters that set the output of the analog pins to current or voltage control? I also tried this already with the [Universal robot Driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver) with the function

> FUN_SET_FLAG

but when i use this function, i get the message that it is not implemented yet in this driver.

thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343898/what-are-flags-in-the-setio-service-of-the-ur-messages/) by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-12**:\

> I also tried this already with the Universal robot Driver but when i use this function, i get the message that it is not implemented yet in this driver

I'm guessing you are referring to `FUN_SET_TOOL_VOLTAGE` here. Would be good to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Are flags the parameters that set the output of the analog pins to current or voltage control?

No.

Flags are (from the *The URScript Programming Language*, version `3.12`):

> Flags behave like internal digital outputs. They keep information between program runs.

They are essentially a set of booleans in memory of the controller, not connected to any physical output or input. They can be used to store simple binary information.

Often used as mutexes or in wait conditions (ie: one thread waits on a flag to become `True` before continuing. Another thread sets the flag to `True` to signal the other thread it may continue).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-12**:
This is just functionality offered by Universal Robots on their controllers btw. Nothing ROS-specific about this.

The `SetIO` service you mention is just a ROS interface to that functionality.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-12**:
Btw: you can configure the tool voltage and other setting using snippets of URScript (see the scripting manual).

The `ur_hardware_interface` node in the `ur_robot_driver` package exposes a urscript topic to which you can send snippets of URScript.

You could use that to configure the settings you are referring to in your question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-12**:
You're right. I've updated my comment.

**Comment by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on 2020-02-12**:
I do not understand what you mean with scripting manual, is it [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-12**:
No.

It's the standard URScript manual as provided by Universal Robots on their support website.

[This one](https://www.universal-robots.com/download/?option=62055) for the CB series controller (not e-Series), system software version `3.12`.

**Comment by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on 2020-02-17**:
With the URScript topic, you mean the `script_command` Topic of the `ur_hardware_interface` node

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-17**:
Yes, see [this](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blame/6f0f2c236fa76ed9ab93fd2961ad3f76dea3ab37/ur_robot_driver/doc/ROS_INTERFACE.md#L839-L841) (or search for `script_command` in [the ROS_INTERFACE docs](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/6f0f2c236fa76ed9ab93fd2961ad3f76dea3ab37/ur_robot_driver/doc/ROS_INTERFACE.md)).

**Comment by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on 2020-02-17**:
i send this to the topic `ur_hardware_interface/script_command` : `'sec myProgram(): set_analog_outputdomain(1,1) end'` .
but it doesnt do anything. when i send `'set_analog_outputdomain(1,1)'` it does set the pin domain correctly but then it interrupts the driver ur_cap that is running (as is mentioned in the documentation you send in the previous comment) my polyscope version is 3.7.1.
Is this not up to date enough? Should i start another question or update this one?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-17**:
Seeing as we're now no longer answering general usage questions, but a potential problem with the implementation of the `script_command` topic provided by `ur_robot_driver`, I would suggest to post an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues).

If/when you do, please:

1. post a comment here with a link to the issue you posted (so we keep things connected)
2. include example code with your issue which shows the problem you are running into

If what you include in your comment is a verbatim copy of what you published to `script_command`, then I believe you need to make sure you include newlines where appropriate. But again: please post an issue.